# OpenCart VQMod Invalid Regex Error

Tags: php, regex, opencart, vqmod

I'm trying to add a bit of code after the checkout->confirm function. I'm trying to add it to all the payment gateways.
The Regex is:

```
\$this->model_checkout_order->confirm.*\);$
```

And in the VqMod file:

```
<file name="catalog/controller/payment/*.php">
    <operation info="In ALL payment gateways, On order confirm, generate the file and upload it">
        <search position="after" error="log" regex="true"><![CDATA[\$this->model_checkout_order->confirm.*\);$]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            //added code here...
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

However, it doesn't work and just leaves

```
INVALID REGEX ERROR - \$this->model_checkout_order->confirm.*\);$
```

In the vqmod.log file.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex values also need you to provide the delimiter of the regex, such as a `~`

```
~\$this->model_checkout_order->confirm.*\);$~
```

you can optionally add the flags at the end for case insensitivity etc

## EDIT

You can actually just do the same thing in your code without regex

```
file name="catalog/controller/payment/*.php">
    <operation info="In ALL payment gateways, On order confirm, generate the file and upload it">
        <search position="after" error="log"><![CDATA[$this->model_checkout_order->confirm(]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            //added code here...
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Comment: Thanks but it still didn't work - SEARCH NOT FOUND (ABORTING MOD): ~\$this->model_checkout_order->confirm.*\);$~
 and then with flags
 ~\$this->model_checkout_order->confirm.*\);$/igm~

Comment: As the error suggests your text you've used there doesn't exist. Also, why do you even need to use a regex for this? Just use the code I've added above